# ¿Porque no aparecen los elementos de la app en el emulador?

Tags: android-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]introducir la descripción de la imagen aquíAl abrir el emulador se me abre la aplicación pero no se ven los elementos que tengo puestos en la aplicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías agregar el código que estás usando (Java y XML) ?

Comment: trataste de cambiar el layout , a nose un relative?

Comment: En la imagen no se aprecia ningún error, comparte el código que tienes en el xml del activity y en tu clase principal para intentar ayudarte.

Comment: Ahí tampoco aprecio ningún fallo, puede que el problema esté en tu clase principal, comparte esa parte del código para comprobarlo.